# Video won't autoplay on mobile safari and firefox

Tags: html

```html
<video autoplay playsinline loop class="desktop">
  <source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0550/6236/4360/files/ARCHIVE.mp4?v=1614799234" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I have an issue that the video won't automatically play at firefox and safari on mobile. I have no idea and I'm out of ideas why the behaviour is just on mobile and not on browser.

Comment: Videos won't autoplay unless muted. It was implemented in all major browsers in the last few years.

Comment: Even if I use muted on firefox I have a icon to play the video and it won't autoplay automatically.

Comment: On iOS your video is working for me, it auto plays, check this out maybe: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari